# Maven keytool-plugin (mojo) exception during clean install

Tags: java, maven, keytool, mojo

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT>/version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <keystore>/path/to/your/keystore</keystore>
      <storepass>storepass</storepass>
      <keypass>keypass</keypass>
      <alias>foo_alias</alias>
      <dname>cn=www.example.com, ou=None, L=Seattle, ST=Washington, o=ExampleOrg, c=US</dname>
      <sigalg>SHA1withDSA</sigalg>
      <ext></ext>
      <validity>100</validity>
      <keyalg>DSA</keyalg>
      <keysize>1024</keysize>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Here is the exception, I am getting.

```
TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG (position: START_TAG seen ...<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT>/version>\n    \t\t\t<executions>... @345:20)  @ line 345, column 20 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelParseException: TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG (position: START_TAG seen ...<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT>/version>\n    \t\t\t<executions>... @345:20) 
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:529)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:469)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:438)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
```

I am new to maven and STS, let me know if anybody knows how to handle this?

Comment: It is showing red cross mark at -> **<executions>** tag

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT>/version>
> ```

this is not valid XML, it must be

```
<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I found this later  when I posted the question. However, I am getting exception here,  **<execution>** as,   --->  Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:keytool-maven-plugin:
 1.6-SNAPSHOT>:generateKeyPair (execution: default, phase: generate-resources)

Comment: Is the plugin between `<pluginManagement>` tags? It shouldn't.

Comment: Actually I referred this example from here, http://www.mojohaus.org/keytool/keytool-maven-plugin/usage.html.  Many references suggest that use pluginmanagement, but still I am unclear about how to do it

Comment: Now I can see where the xml-tag mistake is coming from. Could you create an issue for it? Consider pluginManagement as predefined/shared configuration. If you the plugin to be part of the build-lifecycle, you *must* add it explicitly as a plugin (except those plugins which are already part of the lifecycle, like maven-install-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for clarification,. Could you please refer me that how can I convert those keytool plugin examples to be used with PluginManagement and executor ?